# Limit involving logarithm of factorials

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Evaluate the limit
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(2n)!! - \log(2n-1)!!}{\log n}.$$

Where

$$(2n)!!= 2\cdot 4 \cdot 6  \cdots (2n)$$
$$(2n-1)!!= 1\cdot 3 \cdot 5  \cdots  (2n-1)$$

Comment: What do you mean by "$\log(2n)!!$" ?

Comment: As usual $(2n)!!= 2\cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot ... \cdot (2n)$

Comment: Have you tried converting everything to regular factorials and using Stirling's formula?

Comment: @martin: Not always as usual, it could mean $((2n)!)!$. This should be precised in the question.

Comment: @Greg Martin: We can write $2^n\cdot n!$ for $(2n)!!$, but what to do with the other factorial?

Comment: Hint: $(2n-1)!! = (2n)!/(2n)!!$

Answer (score 1):

$(2n)!!=2^n\,n!\quad$ and $\quad(2n-1)!!=\dfrac{(2n)!}{(2n)!!}=\dfrac{(2n)!}{2^n\,n!}\qquad$ Now use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Answer (score 0):

$$\ldots =\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n} \ln(1+\frac{1}{2j-1})}{\ln n}=\frac{\sum_j \frac{1}{2j-1}-\sum_j \frac{1}{2 (2j-1)^2}+\frac{1}{3(2j-1)^3}-\ldots}{\ln n}$$
The sum of all terms except the first can be bounded by something of order $\frac{O(1)}{\ln n}$ (this requires a bit of work) and 
in the limit, the first term 
$$\frac{\sum_j \frac{1}{2j-1}}{\ln n}=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{j}-\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{2j}}{\ln n}=\frac{\ln 2n - \frac{1}{2} \ln n + o(n)}{\ln n}\mapsto \frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

With Cesaro-Stolz:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log((2n)!!) - \log((2n-1)!!)}{\log n}=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log((2n+2)!!)-\log((2n)!!) - \log((2n+1)!!)+\log((2n-1)!!)}{\log(n+1)-\log n}=
$$

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log
\frac{(2n+2)!!(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!(2n+1)!!}
}{\log((n+1)/n)}=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log
\frac{2(n+1)2(n+1)}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}
}{\log((n+1)/n)}=\cdots
$$